# qt preprocessor

Tags: c++, qt, signals

What is the order of compiling in QT? as I understood it is impossible to write

```
 
#define BEGIN_SIGNALS signals:
```

is the only way to make conditional compilation only using

```
#ifdef QT
signals:
#endif
```

Comment: Having your class be an QObject or not depending on some ifdef sounds broken. How does it implement equivalent functionality for the signal/slot mechanism for the non-Qt case? I'd make two classes out of it.

Comment: at the moment I can not say will it work. But what I want is to replace direct call of QObject::connect and declaration of signals/slots. I just want my code to compile both in visual studio without qt and in QT.)) In visual studio I use FastDelegate library. And why I want to do it because I have delegate only with 2 parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested it and

```
#define BEGIN_SIGNALS signals:
```

does actually work as expected since moc does the preprocessing as well.
The order of compilation for a `QObject` class `MyQObject` is -

```
start moc for MyQObject.h
   moc run the C preprocessor
   moc produces the moc_MyObject.cpp file
moc_MyObject.cpp is compiled by the native compiler
```

`MyQObject.cpp` is compiled by the native compiler before or after this.

Be mindful that the word `signals` itself is a macro that translates to `protected` when the native compiler is used. so I'm not sure why you would ever want to define something like this `BEGIN_SIGNALS`

Comment: thanks, I just want to write some wrapper around QT signal/slot. It allows me to use some other library on other platforms to provide this functionality.

Comment: shoosh actually I tested all the day. but the order is not you wrote. First moc precesses all signals and generate their code in moc file and then launch preprocessor over them. Maybe so. And it is impossible generate signal names by preprocessor. they are taken to moc file as is

Comment: You are right. moc actually doesn't run the preprocessor... If you'll unmark as answered, I'll delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the point of using a macro for an anyway custom keyword?
2. The meta-object compiler invokes the C++ preprocessor, so you're pretty much good using macros for those keywords.
3. If not Qt, then what other toolkit do you expect to rely on for an event-mechanism? In my opinion, there is no point in using overlapping toolkits for development unless you wish to keep specific functionality which can be configured (at compile time in a build setting) which relies on Qt. In this case, you are better off using semantics from a toolchain (automake, cmake, whatever you use).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the other way around.

If not QT then define 'signals'  as 'protected' - which is what Qt does anyway so that compiler doesn't trip up.  You also need to define Q_OBJECT, emit() and connect() to do nothing.

ps. You do sometimes need to do this, I have a low level lib that carefully doesn't depend on Qt - but it can send a Qt signal when an event occurs. Without Qt it can send a windows event or a callback function.